# Automated Apps Script for BigQuery Not Connecting To Right Project?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I'm getting the below problem with apps script which is attempting to run a query and create a table, TEST4, in BigQuery. The error is:

> "Project 603804914871 is not found and cannot be used for API calls.
>   (line 19, file "Code")"

Query is:

```
saveQueryToTable() {
      var projectId = 'fiery-cabinet-****';
      var datasetId = '11234***1';
      var tableId = 'TEST4';
      var job = {
        configuration: {
          query: {
            query: 'SELECT *' +
                   'FROM Test2;',
            destinationTable: {
              projectId: projectId,
              datasetId: datasetId,
              tableId: tableId
            }
          }
        }
      };

  var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId);
  Logger.log(queryResults.status);
}
```

Could anyone let me know where I'm going wrong?

I can find that project in my console, I can enable the bigquery API for that project and then I don't get any errors... however it doesn't run the query or save to a new table "TEST4"?

Comment: Try to create a new script for this and make sure you on the BigQuery API in the Advance Google Service of your Script. Also, enable it on your Developer Console. Note that all the API in the Advance Google Services must also be enabled in the [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com).

Comment: Hi @KENdi I have enabled BQ in resources then gone to the script project in the console and enabled the BQ api there as well as the apps script execution api just for good measure. The script seems to execute fine, I get not errors but nothing seems to be happening on the BQ side... I also have all APIs enabled on the BQ project in question. Thanks

Comment: if you don't get error anymore - so you might either close your question or update it - or it is not clear what is that you are asking now!

Comment: Hi, to be clear I don't get that particular error now, which is great, but nothing seems to be happening when I run the script i.e. a table called TEST4 is not created nor if I change the table to an already created table does it update - is there something wrong with the script itself?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I've added an edit to my question so hopefully it's clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response from @KENDi was correct. I had to enable the API in the Google Developer Console.