# BigQuery Automation: What is the best way to run a query every day and write the result into another table?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

[Standard SQL] I want to run a query every day and write the results into another table (so that the table is appended by one row each day). What is the best way of doing so? My initial idea is to have a query of the following structure:

```
INSERT INTO `project.dataset.table2` (column1, column2)
SELECT
  column1,
  column2
FROM
  `project.dataset.table21`
WHERE column1 = CURRENT_DATE()
```

And to create a [job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query) for running the query every day:

```
{ "kind": "bigquery#queryRequest",
      "query": "SELECT ...",
      "timeoutMs": 600000,
      "useQueryCache": true,
      "useLegacySql": false,
      "parameterMode": "POSITIONAL"
}
```

How can I trigger that this job is executed every day at a specific time?
Is there a better approach for achieving what I want to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I trigger that this job is executed every day at a specific time?

You can use App Engine Cron Service to automate BigQuery query execution
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/features/#cron
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bigquery-api-quickstart

Another option would be to use Google Apps Script to script BigQuery query with a Time based trigger to execute script
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers

Yet, another option is recently introduced  Google Cloud Functions (Beta)
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/

> As of using job - Is there a better approach for achieving what I want to do?

You rather should use [`Job.insert`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert) with query property and define [`query.destinationTable`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.query.destinationTable) property

Comment: Thanks, Mikhail! Do you know what access level I need for the Google Apps variant? I get the following error message: "Project ... is not found and cannot be used for API calls. "

Comment: You have to enable the BigQuery API in both the Advance Google Services within Scripts and in the Google Developer Console. (as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978707/automated-apps-script-for-bigquery-not-connecting-to-right-project )

Answer (score 2):

This might have not been available at the time of this Question and Answer.
But the better solution now would be to use the Scheduled Query feature built into BiqQuery itself.  No need to stand up App Engine Services or create work arounds with other services just to kick off a timely query.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries

Answer (score 1):

You can alose used gcloud  bq command line for execute script and insert this result in table.

With option, you can choose table and partition with select$YYYYMMDD

Exemple :

```
bq query  --destination_table=DATASET.TABLE$YYYYMMDD append_table=true -n 0 'select colA from table'
```